# How do I code a cat recognizer with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I want to code a cat recognizer with OpenCV using the Python module [face-recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/).
This code works for **human** faces, using [haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml) (this is the trained model).

```
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("recognition/dataset"))

knownEncodings = []
knownNames = []

# For each image, we analyze the face on it
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):

    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb, model="hog")

    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

    for encoding in encodings:
        knownEncodings.append(encoding)
        knownNames.append(name)

data = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}

# We save the data in a file
f = open("recognition/encodings.pickle", "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
f.close()
```

I tried to use [haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml), to recognize **cats**. I recorded my cats, but the recognition program didn't recognize any cat using the `encodings.pickle`. Python didn't throw any error. The program worked fine for humans.

Does the `face_recognition` module work for cats?

Comment: haar cascades usually are based on trainings for pattern recognition. You probably will need to create a training yourself to use for cats.

Comment: My Program detect cats using the cat haarcascade, but face_recognition didn't recognize any cat...

Comment: I think [haarcascade_frontalcatface](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml) can only be used for cat detection. There is nothing mentioning about recognition - which certainly would demand a deeper training data.

Comment: Yes. I was not clear. There is no problem with the detection. The problem is that `face_recognition` doesn't give a valid encoding.

Answer (score 1):

**Detection**: Knowing if and where a photo contains a face
**Recognition**: Knowing who the face belongs to (is it Billy or Emily?)

Cat face detection is possible, recognition is not since the recognition model used in this module was trained on humans and I don't see any evidence of a cat trained recognition model.

**Detection** of human faces is in general harder than detection of animal faces, because [human faces have more variety](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/09/140916112240.htm#:%7E:text=The%20amazing%20variety%20of%20human,of%20California%2C%20Berkeley%2C%20scientists.) than animal faces. While this variation makes **detection** harder, it actually makes correct **recognition** easier. The converse is true for cats - they have less facial variety making **detection** easier but **recognition** harder.

## Detection

The error you are getting sounds like the basic recognition is failing. That needs to be fixed before you can attempt recognition. Cat face detection is definitely feasible using the [face-recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/) module (it is listed in the examples, as well as demonstrated [here](https://nummist.com/opencv/Howse_ISMAR_20140909.pdf) and [here](https://techtutorialsx.com/2021/04/11/python-opencv-detect-cat-faces/)):

```
import cv2
 
catFaceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/N/Desktop/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
 
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/N/Desktop/test.jpg')
 
faces = catFaceCascade.detectMultiScale(image)
 
if len(faces) == 0:
    print("No faces found")
 
else:
    print("Number of faces detected: " + str(faces.shape[0]))
 
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0))
 
    cv2.imshow('Image with faces', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

## Recognition

Without models trained on cats, you won't be able to do recognition. The [`face_recognition`](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/face_recognition/api.py) api relies on several models to function (all trained on human faces) which you could try replacing with models trained on cats if you have them.

Comment: question was about recognition, not detection, as was clarified by OP in a comment under the other answer.

Comment: And I've answered that without cat specific models, recognition is not possible. OPs error indicated that detection could be an issue too, and anyone landing here will need to understand the difference (and might be looking for detection anyway) so I've included both.